# Send data using JQuery (redirectPost) and Net 6

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I am migrating an application from the .Net Framework to .Net 6
But I have a problem, when I click "Download Report" I send data from the view to the controller, but "filterOptions" is always null in the controller.

I show the code below.

```
<button id="btnReport">Download Report</button>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control select2" id="selectFilter" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="OK">OK</option>
        <option value="ERROR">ERROR</option>
   </select>
</div>
    
<script>
    var filterOptions = {
        Options: [],
        Data: '',
    }

    function AddFilters(options, data) {
        filterOptions.Options = options;
        filterOptions.Data = data       
    }

    //selectFilter: Ok, Error

    '#btnReport': function (e) {
    
        AddFilters(
            $('#selectFilter').select2('data').map((x) => x.id) 
            , $('#txtData').val()
        );
    
        var startDate = moment($('#rStartDate').datepicker('getDate'));
        var endDate = moment($('#rEndDate').datepicker('getDate'));

        return $.redirectPost('@Url.Action("MyMethod", "Controller")', 
                                { 
                                    startDate.toISOString(),
                                    endDate.toISOString(),
                                    filterOptions 
                                });
    }
 </script>
```

This is my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(DateTime? startDate,
                                 DateTime? endDate,
                                 Filters filterOptions)
    {
        /*More code*/
    }
    
    
    public class Filters
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Options { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
```

I do not understand what the problem is.
I hope you can help me.

Thank you

Comment: What's the details of `filterOptions` could you please share the model with us? Or share the code in way so that it can be reproduced.

Comment: I think the problem may be in the content of `filterOptions`, you can break the point to see if it corresponds to the properties of `Filters`.

Comment: Does your controller directly show that `filterOptions` is empty, or is the property in it empty?

Comment: When I use string[] and string as the value of `filterOptions`, I can see the corresponding value in the controller.

Comment: Hi, I updated the code, added <select class="form-control select2" id="selectFilter" multiple="multiple">. In the AddFilters function I add the selectFilter items to filterOptions.Options.

Comment: @Chen In the browser console I can see that filterOptions.Options has [''OK", "ERROR"] In the controller the (Filters) filterOptions property arrives empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you considering using `ajax` to make the call?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '@Url.Action("MyMethod", "Controller")',
        data: { startDate, endDate, filterOptions },
        success: function (result) {
            //...
        },
        error: function (error){
        }
});
```